# When do I need to use each in jquery

Tags: jquery, each

If I have for instance some HTML like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">one</li>
    <li><a href="#">two</li>
    <li><a href="#">three</li>
</ul
```

and I want to use jquery to affect the anchor tag in each of those `li` items. Under which circumstances would I need to use `each` to cycle betwen them and under which circumstances would the jquery automatically apply to all of the `li`'s

for instance if I do

```
jQuery('ul li a').css('color', 'red');
```

this will make every a tag red, but is this the case no matter which method I use, and are there other scenarios ( different HTML or selectors ) where I would need to use `each`.

Comment: Usually if you want to *read* the state of each element in a set (one way or the other), you have to iterate over them. E.g. `.attr` only returns the value of the first selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery('ul li a').css('color', 'red')` is an example where the color would be `red`. However, you can use `$.each` for lets say you have to do some processing before applying the color `red`. Example:

```
$('ul li a').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().hasAttr('error')){  
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

You could not do the check in the first case, but you can using `.each`

Comment: yes, thanks ... but are there not some scenarios in jqery where only the first instance in the dom is matched unless you use each ... of have i got that completely wrong.

Comment: that would happen only when you use IDs, or that is the only match. Ca n you point out to a situation that you are mentioning?

Comment: I thought I could but actually it seems I've got some misunderstanding about this ... I see now anyway ... I only probably NEED to use each if I need to run a function like you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something more complex you can run a function.

For example If you want to do an alert on each element:

```
$('ul li a').each(function(index, value) { alert(index); });
```

Answer (score 1):

A large majority of the time, `each` is redundant or implied. Use `each` if you need something unique to that particular element (primary example being `id`).

Using `$('ul li a').attr('id')` to find the the `id` would only provide the first `id`. This means you would have to use:

```
$('ul li a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to iterate throughout child elements you can use `each`. No matter if they are lists, set of div, spans or paragraphs.

Whenever you want to write some logic for every children in wrapper you can use `each`

Example :

```
$('#oneDiv div').each(function(){
     if(div.text() === null)
        //do Something
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the jQuery API documentation: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function, for your example it isn't necessary as shown in their example.

```js
// The .each() method is unnecessary here:
$( "li" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "foo" );
});

// Instead, you should rely on implicit iteration:
$( "li" ).addClass( "bar" );
```